# how to combine 2 table per id

Tags: sql, database

I got 2 tables, with same champ, here an example:

TABLE 1

```
ID    date
1     05/05/2020
1     07/05/2020
1     11/07/2020
2     08/05/2013
2     08/05/2014
3     05/05/2009
```

TABLE 2

```
ID    date
1     15/05/2020
2     29/08/2014
```

I would like with these 2 table got something like this :

```
ID    date
1     05/05/2020
1     07/05/2020
1     11/07/2020
**1     15/05/2020**
2     08/05/2013
2     08/05/2014
**2     29/08/2014**
3     05/05/2009
```

So like you can see, my 2 lines on my second table got under the last id

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union all with an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```py
SELECT ID, date FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, date FROM TABLE2
ORDER BY ID, date;
```

Comment: @seb . . . This doesn't actually "work".  The row for id = 1 from table 2, for instance, would be the third row rather than the fourth -- assuming the dates are properly stored as dates and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are consider about exact order, ie., **second table got under the last id**, you are required to add the order id column to achieve it.

```
SELECT ID, [Date] FROM (
    SELECT ID, [Date], 1 AS OrderId FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, [Date], 2 AS OrderId FROM Table2
) Q
ORDER BY ID, OrderId
```

[Working demo in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3146d59ec84e460dd0cbfe934e0de62)